# migration from Cloudera Hadoop to HDINSIGHT

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, azure-hdinsight

Can anyone tell me. I have HQL scripts that I used to run on Cloudera using hive -f scriptname.hql Now I want to run on these scripts in HDINSIGHT(Hadoop cluster) but the hive command line is not available in HDINSIGHT. Can someone guide how I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create an environment variable :**

```
export hivef="beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://hn0-hdi-uk.witechmill.co.uk:10001/default;principal=hive/_HOST@witechmill.CO.UK;auth-kerberos;transportMode=http' -n umerrkhan "
```

witechmill is my clustername

**Then call the script by using the below**

```
$hivef scriptname.hql
```

Answer (score 0):

beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://headnodehost:10001/;transportMode=http' -i query.hql

Anyone has experience of using above rather than

hive -f query.hql

Comment: What aus the beat place to out hql files. 
- Head node 
- A separate VM with client Beeline installed.

Comment: The best place to put hql files is to  use an edge in Hdinsight cluster

Answer (score 0):

I don't see there is any other way to execute the HQL files.You can refer to this document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-use-hive-beeline#run-a-hiveql-file

You can also use the zookeeper quorum(encircled) to avoid failure of queries during head node failover

[image]

```
beeline -u '<zookeeper quorum>' -i /path/query.hql
```